# Matrix assembley

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to assemble local stiffness matrix to global one. Each node has 3Dof. The problem is I don't know how to shift the matrices at last part while adding process.

The code is:

```
clc; clear;
el_tot = 3; %number of elements
n_tot = 3*(el_tot+1); %number of nodes
% LOCAL - TO - GLOBAL MAPPING
EL_N = [ 1:3: n_tot-3 ; 6:3: n_tot ];
% INITIALIZE GLOBAL STIFFNESS MATRIX AND GLOBAL FORCE VECTOR
K = zeros ( n_tot , n_tot );
shift = 0;
% ELEMENT LOOP
for iel = 1: el_tot
    % GET NODE INDICES FOR ELEMENT iel
    el_nodes = EL_N (: , iel);
    % DEFINE ELEMENT STIFFNESS MATRIX AND VECTOR
    Kloc = ones(6,6);
    % INSERT / SUM LOCAL ELEMENT STIFFNESS MATRICES
    % INTO GLOBAL STIFFNESS MATRIX
    K ( el_nodes, el_nodes  ) = K ( el_nodes , el_nodes   ) + Kloc ;
end
```

Comment: `Kloc` is always 6-by-6 while `K(el_nodes,el_nodes)` is always 2-by-2, how do you expect to sum them?

Comment: Thank you, I rewrite it!